# How to remove the time and minus one day in Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, formatting, powerquery

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a column showing date and time. I want to remove the time behind the date and then minus one day off from the date. For example, if the date and time is `8/18/2019 6:51:00PM`, the final output will be `8/17/2019`. Or if the date and time is `10/27/2019 6:23:00PM`, then the out put will be `10/26/2019`. How to achieve this in Power Query? The output column should be a new column instead of replacing the old column. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Power Query, go to the ribbon on top and press 'Add Column', on the left side you will now see 'Custom Column'

[image: Add new column]

Here you can type a formula. I've made the following:

[image: Power Query]